# Bracket Overload for Assignment and Retrieval; const, reference

Tags: c++, overloading, accessor, brackets, mutators

Regarding overloading brackets in C++, my compiler is using the mutator method for access. Can anyone tell me why?

```
1. const int & Cheese::operator [] (int i)const { return weight[i]; } //accessor
2. int & Cheese::operator [] (int i) { return weight[i]; } //mutator
```

For example, the cout command below is using the mutator function definition--#2 above--to access the data.

```
Cheese cheddar;
cout << cheddar[2] << endl;
```

Why is this not using the first function--the accessor--to get the data? I would think that, since the cout is simply a retrieval, it would fire on the first.

How does the compiler know which of these to invoke?

EDIT: For completeness, by mutator, I mean used as a "setter," like so:

```
cheddar[2] = 100;
```

Both together would be as follows:

```
cheddar[2] = cheddar[1];
```

Where the rhs is just a "getter." It simply retrieves the value of *cheddar[1]*, does not change anything, and thus can be const. In contrast, the lhs bracket overload *cheddar[2]* functions as a "setter;" the value can be changed, and function return value can't be const.

Comment: `const` (i.e. following the function declaration) for the class instance is the culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It invokes the first one for any constant instance (like `const Cheese` or `const Cheese&`) and the second one for mutable instances.

Comment: oooooh ok... I thought that it was contextual. tyvm :) I understood these as "getters and setters," where #1 would be used to get, and #2 to set. Here the compiler uses #1 for getting data from const instances, and #2 to both get AND set data for mutable instances. #epiphany

Answer (score 2):

In case you care about a way you *can* get roughly the effect you seem to want (specifically, to have one function executed to get the value, and other code to set the value, dependably), there is a way to do that.

The usual way is to return a proxy instead of returning the value (or a reference to it) directly. The proxy overloads `operator T` and `operator=`.

```
template <class T>
class Proxy { 
    T value;
public:
    Proxy(T v) : value(v) {}

    // used only to get value
    operator T() const { return value; } 

    // used only to set value
    Proxy &operator=(T new_value) { 
        value = new_value;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Then your overload just returns an instance of this:

```
Proxy<Cheese &> operator[](int i) { return Proxy<int>(weight[i]); }
Proxy<Cheese const &> operator[](int i) const { return Proxy<int>(weight[i]); }
```

Note that in the second case, `T` has the type `Cheese const &` and `operator=` isn't a `const` member function, so you won't be able to use `operator=` in this case (which is exactly what you normally want).

Comment: So then, what would the instance usage look like? With this proxy, would __cout << cheddar[1] << endl;__ be correct for getting? __cheddar[2] = 100;__ for setting?

Comment: Yes--you'd use it just as if the `operator[]` was doing things directly. The one place it makes a big difference is if you were depending on a user-defined conversion happening implicitly (this already uses an implicit, user-defined conversion, and only one is allowed in an expression).